# Access Azure Key Vault with Managed Identity on Azure Batch running .NET Console Application

Tags: .net, azure-keyvault, azure-batch, azure-identity, defaultazurecredential

**Is it possible to access Azure Key Vault Secrets with Azure Managed Identity setup on the Azure Batch?** I've read through Microsoft docs and the only option I technically see is using certificate based authentication to access key vault within the .net console application. Since Managed Identities can be used in Azure Batch, I figured `DefaultAzureCredential` could be taken advantage of. I've had no luck in getting it to work.

**Has anyone been able to get it to work like this, or am I going to have to settle for using certificate based authentication?** *Microsoft if you see this... Is there something in the works to get something like this working with Managed Identities*

Technologies in play:

- Azure Managed Identity: User-Assigned (id: xxxx)
- Azure Key Vault

  - Added Managed Identity (id: xxx) to access policy with secrets access: get, list
- Azure Batch

  - Batch Pool

    - Managed Identity (id: xxxx) Installed
    - Application: .Net Console Application (where code below resides)
- .Net Console Application

  - .Net6

Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
DefaultAzureCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential( 
    new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
      {
         ManagedIdentityClientId = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
      });
            
Uri uri = new("https://xxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/"); //Also Tried "https://xxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/"
            
SecretClient client = new(uri, credential);
var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
return secret?.Value.Value;
```

Error I receive from Batch Job's Task (filtered to show the ManagedIdentityCredential error)

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)

Content:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}

Headers:
Server: IMDS/150.870.65.684
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2022 17:47:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 68

   at Azure.Identity.ImdsManagedIdentitySource.HandleResponseAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, Response response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ImdsManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](ValueTask`1 task)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.ChallengeBasedAuthenticationPolicy.AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.ChallengeBasedAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessCoreAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.ChallengeBasedAuthenticationPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted(ValueTask task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.Send(HttpMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.SendRequest(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequest(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequest[TResult](RequestMethod method, Func`1 resultFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String[] path)
   at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.SecretClient.GetSecret(String name, String version, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at wileyulab.infrastructure.SimpleService.Execute(String[] args) in C:\AzDo\WileyU\wiley-u-lab\wileyulab.infrastructure\SimpleService.cs:line 55
   at wileyulab.consoleapp.simple.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\AzDo\WileyU\wiley-u-lab\wileyulab.consoleapp.simple\Program.cs:line 70
```

Comment: Do you have the proper `AZURE_TENANT_ID` set?

Comment: Have you configure the user-assigned identity correctly ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/managed-identity-pools

Comment: I have exactly the same issue doing the same steps/code - did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @RanSagy - you need to create a pool with the user created managed identity associated with it in order to use the identity from the Batch node

Comment: @Gaurav I did do that, I can it is associated in the portal. However, I still can't get the ManagedIdentity portion of DefaultAzureCredential to pick on it. I also have AZURE_TENANT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_ID env vars set. the code also gives the DefaultAzureCredential initializer the value of AZURE_CLIENT_ID as the ManagedIdentity ID - the same one associated with the pool.

Comment: @RanSagy - are you sure you did it for the `pool` and not the `Batch account` itself?

you have specifically create a pool with `User assigned identity` associated with the pool during creation.

Once you do that, you can use the identity with `DefaultAzureCredentials` like you have mentioned:

on C#:

`new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = <client-id> });
`

I have done something similar with python sdk too

Comment: @Gaurav My path is pretty similar but a little bit different - I created the pool with the Azure CLI and/or Azure Powershell module, which can't give an identity during creation, and then HTTP PATCH'd it with an identity. Maybe something in that breaks the process, not sure. My .NET Code is exactly like what you've shown.

Comment: @RanSagy - can you validate if the identity is actually being assigned to the pool by looking at the properties blade of the pool via Azure Portal? There's a field/property called `User-assigned managed identities` in the properties of the pool. That should have your user assigned identity.

Comment: @Gaurav It is being assigned, yes. After a bit more trial and error, i figured out the difference in my scenario and it works now - I was creating the pool without the identity, as said (can't be done with the az CLI/Az powershell module yet, which is what i use in this scenario) but also with a target spot/low-prio node count of 1, meaning the machine was live before PATCH'ing in the identity happened. There's a restart to the nodes after all of that, but that wasn't enough apparently; the IMDS service still failed until i re-scaled to 0 and back to 1 to get a new machine, then it worked.

Comment: @RanSagy Wow. that spot vm was an edge case I didn't think of! Nice. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Gaurav I'm pretty sure a dedicated machine would act the same, just requires the identity configuration to exist before the machine enters the pool, it seems. Thanks for the tips to push me in the right direction though :)

Comment: @RanSagy - Thanks - you pointed me in the right direction. I tried switching to another pool I had that was created with a managed identity assigned to it at the point of creation, and this worked. I presume it is the same thing - the node was booted up with the identity assigned, rather than being assigned after boot. Manually rebooting existing nodes in the portal didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @SethFlowers Good to know it helped! Yeah the behavior seems a little tricky and not fully documented from what i could tell, it really has to be done when the pool is created or it doesn't react properly. Maybe something to do with how the metadata service on the machine works, not sure. But at least there's a way to get it going :)

Answer (score 0):

The error  below may occur due to one of the following actions not properly configured.

> Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException:
> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested
> identity has not been assigned to this resource.

- Please make sure to ENABLE  managed identity in the Azure service
  before using . [image]
- As you have you user-asigned managed identity with the
  DefaultAzureCredential  ,you need to provide the ***`client Id`***
  and  make sure specify the clientId in code by setting
  ***`environment variables`***.

  > ```
  > AZURE_CLIENT_ID - service principal's app id
  > AZURE_TENANT_ID - principal's Azure Active Directory tenantId
  > AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET - service principal's client secrets
  > ```
- Make sure the managed identity is granted proper **`role`** like
  `contributor or reader` to   access the batch and keyvault.
- In the Azure portal, after the Key Vault is created,please add the
  Batch account access using managed identity  in the Access Policy
  under Setting which is  Under Key Permissions. select
  *Get,list,create, Wrap Key and Unwrap Key etc* which are needed

  [image]

Note:

> And **please Wait** for at least 15 minutes for  role to propagate and
> then try to access.

> Please make sure you are logged in into Visual Studio within azure
> with proper roles/rights  as Managed identity can  work only when it
> is running in the Azure service. It will NOT work when run locally.

**References:**

1. [Configure customer-managed keys for your Azure Batch account with
   Azure Key Vault and Managed Identity - Azure Batch | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-customer-managed-key)
2. [TROUBLESHOOTING· GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#verify-the-app-service-managed-identity-endpoint-is-available)